# Software to search for shared files/folders in all machines in a Windows network

Tags: windows, software-rec, search, network-shares

I am on a Windows network and would like to search for files and folders across all the shared folders in the network.

What is a good software/tool that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two free utilities that claim the ability to search local and shared files.

[**neoSearch**](http://www.koshyjohn.com/software/neosearch.html)
See also this article : [neoSearch: Index & Search Shared Folders On The Network](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/neosearch-index-network-locations-search-shared-folders/)

> Why neoSearch? Because it the most
>   simplest lightweight search tool
>   available today. What I like the most
>   is the fast indexing speed and the
>   real-time search results, which
>   according to the developer, are
>   displayed in less than 0.01 seconds
>   after you type a keyword or hit Enter.

[**LAN Search Pro – Free network file locator**](http://www.softperfect.com/products/lspro/)

> LAN Search Pro is a powerful utility
>   for fast file searching across your
>   LAN. You can search for specific file
>   names or for specific file types (e.g.
>   all MP3 files). LAN Search Pro
>   provides a lightning fast search
>   engine and includes the ability to
>   search hidden network resources,
>   restricted access resources, IP
>   subnets, LAN FTP servers and much
>   more. It comes with a built-in
>   password manager to store your network
>   logins for resources with restricted
>   access. Besides the file searching
>   capabilities, LAN Search Pro offers
>   features that allow you to perform
>   actions on the found items – copy,
>   move, rename etc. Additional features
>   include result sorting, filtering,
>   export, search within results,
>   minimize to tray, and more.

Answer (score 0):

The excellent [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) searcher.

> To search a networked computer you will need to run Everything on both computers.
>   One computer will need to Start an ETP server.
>   The other computer will need to connect to that ETP server.

May or may not suit your requirements.

Comment: This, unfortunately doesn't work because I don't have write access to install Everything on the other computers in the network. I only want to search for shared files on these computers that are there on the network.