# How can I search for a specific file on a Windows LAN?

Tags: windows, networking, search, lan

I am new at a site which is about five years old. The primary IT guy has left and no-one remaining knows where certain software has been loaded.

I know the name of the .exe - how can I quickly search to find which server it is located on?

Comment: Might be better asked on Super User?

Comment: More like Moderate User... Just navigate to the folder and press search in your operating system's file manager.

Comment: Blindy - I think you missed something. It sounds like the file may be on one of several machines. I.e. if I understand correctly Wichitan is asking how to run a single search across multiple computers. Still might be better addressed on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/). You'll have to add the networked drives and let it index it but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If the machines on the network are running Windows software, the answer at [Software to search for shared files/folders in all machines in a Windows network](https://superuser.com/questions/127505/software-to-search-for-shared-files-folders-in-all-machines-in-a-windows-network) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to index drivers, map share or connect using admin C$, D$ etc, I would recommand a software called Malicious File Hunter at maliciousfilehunter.com

It's for malware researchers, but I don't see why it won't be useful for pure file search.

Answer (score 0):

#### Neo Search Pro

You can try [Neo Search Pro](http://www.koshyjohn.com/software/neosearch.html). Its new 'Network Search' feature searches every network drive you are connected to. It is also simple to use and efficient.

*It has come to my attention that Neo Search Pro triggers a SmartScreen warning. You can dismiss this, there is no malware.*

#### Everything

You could also try [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) as mentioned above. It's reliable, easy to use as well as the option to download it in a portable executable.